# Mount directory (external hdd) to docker correctly

Tags: docker

I try to start a container and give it access to an external hdd

I started the container with:

```
docker run -d -p 4443:4443 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -v ncdata:/data --name nextcloudpi ownyourbits/nextcloudpi --mount source=/media/ansi/Backup_4TB,destination=/mnt 192.168.103.44
```

The host shows the content of the directory, but the container does not:

```
ansi@ansi-itx:~$ ls /media/ansi/Backup_4TB
iobroker  ncp-backups  ncp-config_20190607.tar  ncp-config_20190614.tar
ansi@ansi-itx:~$ docker exec -it nextcloudpi bash
root@6921e5850765:/# ls /mnt
root@6921e5850765:/#
```

How do I have to do it correctly?

```
docker inspect nextcloudpi
[
    {
        "Id": "6921e5850765e95e071b26f7c247e67adaf04f65c778e4ef38e3943d8c37340a",
        "Created": "2021-03-21T09:06:10.906777692Z",
        "Path": "/run-parts.sh",
        "Args": [
            "--mount",
            "source=/media/ansi/Backup_4TB,destination=/mnt",
            "192.168.103.44"
        ],
```

Comment: Did you read this chapter [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) in the docs?

Comment: You're passing `--mount` as the main command to the container.  If you want it to be interpreted as a Docker option, it needs to go before the image name.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidMaze, but this leads to
docker run -d -p 4443:4443 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -v ncdata:/data --mount source=/media/ansi/Backup_4TB,destination=/mnt --name nextcloudpi ownyourbits/nextcloudpi  192.168.103.44
docker: Error response from daemon: create /media/ansi/Backup_4TB: "/media/ansi/Backup_4TB" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
ansi@ansi-itx:~$